# how do i redirect a user in ember.js without changing the window.location

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In ember.js (I am using 1.1.2) How do I 'send/redirect' a user to a particular url programmatically (without forcefully changing window.location.href).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the guide on redirection](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/).

Ember allows you to transition to a route via it's name or it's URL:

```
router.transitionTo('post', post)
router.transitionTo('/posts/1')
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure of a good way to attain a reference to the router from outside your Ember application other than the very discouraged App.**container**.lookup('router:main'). If you can still handle this UI interaction within your Ember app, it's as simple as adding an action (a method inside the actions hash) to your ApplicationRoute.

Manipulating window.location is probably the 'cleanest' way of triggering a transition from outside your Ember app.

Comment: how would i get a reference to router?

Comment: Try `this.transitionTo` inside of a Route, and/or `this.transitionToRoute` inside of a Controller (typically somewhere in your `actions` hash).

Comment: what im actually after is a way to do it from outside of a controller/route, i.e. as part of some kind of external condition or UI interaction.

Comment: Ah - well in that case the crux of the problem is attaining a reference to your router. I'm not sure of a good way to do so from _outside_ your Ember application other than the _very_ discouraged `App.__container__.lookup('router:main')`. If you can still handle this UI interaction within your Ember app, it's as simple as adding an action (a method inside the `actions` hash) to your ApplicationRoute.

Comment: Come to think of it, manipulating window.location is probably the 'cleanest' way of triggering a transition from outside your Ember app.

Comment: post your last two coments as the answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

I have a hybrid application, where we run some `legacy` code and an Ember "app". In order to make the boundaries really explicit, we created a simply library we called the 'LegacyBridge'. It helps external code call into Ember without having to know too much about the internals. It's also a nice way to limit what external code can do with your Ember App, since there's a lot they could do and it's a good idea to keep limit the options.

Anyway, here's what you could do:

```
var transitionTo, getContainer;

var getContainer = function() {
  return App.__container__;
};

var transitionTo = function(route) {
  var router = Ordering.__container__.lookup('router:main');
  router.transitionTo(route);
};

this.App.LegacyBridge = {
  transitionTo: transitionTo
};
```

Then somewhere in the non-Ember code:

```
App.LegacyBridge.transitionTo('posts/1');
```

This is certainly hacky. In general I wouldn't lookup things directly from the container, but since it's well encapsulate and this is more of an exceptional use case I can live with it.

BTW, this is better than changing the URL, since everything will work even if your router changes the location strategy from history to hash or none, if the rootUrl changes or for browsers not supporting pushState (Ember now will fallback to hash)

Hope this helps.